# How should the data of an index array of a VBO be formatted?

Tags: opengl

I am trying to implement a VBO in my application. Now I have understood how they work, and how to use them, yet I don't have a single clue on how to fill the accompanying index buffer. Strangely enough I haven't found any tutorial explaining this at all.

Say that I have 3 buffers like this:

vertex buffer: (3, 4, 7), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 2), ...

texture buffer: (1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), ..

normal buffer: (4, 2, 6), (3, 2, 7), (2, 4, 5) ...

How do I tell openGL that I want it to draw a vertex at (3, 4, 7) with a texture coordinate of (1, 1) and a normal of (4, 2, 6) and so on? And how do I put this data in the right format in the elements index buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index buffer just contains integer offsets into your VBO arrays.  For your example your first index buffer element should be `0`, since you want to draw the zeroth element of your vertex, texture, and normal arrays.

Note that it's the *same* offset into all three arrays.

Comment: Makes sense. One little thing though; you edited my post so that each coordinate has brackets around them. Is that how they are stored inside a buffer? (i.e. one vertex is one element rather than 3 elements; 1 for x, y and z?) That might be part of why I don't seem to get the buffers to work.

Comment: A vertex can have 1 to 4 coordinates, depending on how the buffer is defined. Additionally, if an interleaved array is used, there might be other data in between, so you could also add a stride (default is 0).

Comment: Thus, if you use glVertexAttribPointer for example, you have to specify type (byte, short, integer etc.), size (number of coordinates: 1 to 4) and stride (size of one buffer entry, i.e. bytes between the start of two vertices).